# how to set cleaning cache timeout in play framework using cacheApi?

Tags: java, scala, caching, playframework

Im using `cacheApi` in my play application, and I wonder if I can have some timeout for cache cleaning?

Im using the `cacheApi` object in a method as `if the data is in cache bring from cache, if not, so go get it from the server with an api call`

and now I want every 24 hrs to clean the cache to be able to bring a new data from the server.

How an I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to configure the timeout:

```
CacheConfiguration<Long, String> cacheConfiguration = CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Long.class, String.class,
        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100)) 
    .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))) 
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Play Framework v2.5: Use [CacheApi.set](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.CacheApi) method and pass needed expiration time to set time to leave (TTL) for cached value.

Play Framework v2.6: Use [SyncCacheApi.set](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.SyncCacheApi) or [AsyncCacheApi.set](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.AsyncCacheApi). Also you can create timer and call [AsyncCacheApi.removeAll](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.AsyncCacheApi) after some period of time (but it's not clear - is it ok for you to remove just added values (let say added 5 minutes before)?

**By default expiration time is infinite - it will never be removed from cache!**